# Why 9 points determine a quadric

Tags: analytic-geometry, projective-geometry

The books I have state this redult as obvious from the definitions, but it is not clear to me why this is so.

Comment: What books do you mean?

Comment: McCrea's three dimensional geometry

Answer (score 1):

A generic quadric surface has equation:
$$
ax^2+by^2+cz^2+dxy+cxz+eyz+fx+gy+hz+k=0
$$
You can alway divide for a not null coefficient so you have $9$ independent coefficients that you can determine giving $9$ points.